# how to get recently closed app timings in android

Tags: android

```
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
System.out.println(recentTasks.size());

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++){           
    String LocalApp = recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent + ""; 
}
```

Using above the code ,i got recently closed app name and package name .

Is their any possible way to get app closing time